# When is a new SSH host key generated?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, hosts, fingerprint, known-hosts

I copied an EC2 instance from an AMI image and brought it back up. After that I had to remove the entry in my `known_hosts` file because the SSH host key fingerprint changed. However, I thought that the key should be the same since the disk contains exactly the same data. Hence my question:

When is the SSH host key regenerated?
And why does it change when I copy and restart an EC2 instance?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct for regular hosts. Maybe cloud-init does some magic here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigating this myself!

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1089348/40350) on a similar Server Fault question states:

> Run `grep ssh /var/log/cloud-init.log`. Apparently cloud-init will regenerate keys/fingerprints if the VM's instance ID changes. This file seems to have a long history so it should be easy to tell if it happened around your timeframe.

The Server Fault question:

- [ubuntu - Host key changing during reboot - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1084435/host-key-changing-during-reboot)